# Creating a table from an exixting table in different pattern?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, union

I'm using SQL Server. I have a table in my database which is like

```
id    stops    time1    time2    time3    time4
-----------------------------------------------
1    Exit1    6:00 AM  8:00 AM  10:00 AM  12:00 PM
2    Exit2    7:00 AM  9:00 AM  11:00 AM  1:00 PM
```

There are more rows like above.

But I would like to create another table which will just use those id and put time# in separate column against respective id like this:

```
id    times
------------
1    6:00 AM
1    8:00 AM
1    10:00 AM
1    12:00 PM
2    7:00 AM
2    9:00 AM
```

Can anyone please give me a head start? Or even a solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what about `11:00 AM  1:00 PM` for id = 2 ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i just put an example. there would more rows like those.

Comment: There is [no PIVOT command in MySQL](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) so I think @Linger answer is good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just run four separate queries to get the desired results ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce90b/1/0)):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(id, times)
SELECT id, time1
FROM MyOtherTable

INSERT INTO MyTable
(id, times)
SELECT id, time2
FROM MyOtherTable

INSERT INTO MyTable
(id, times)
SELECT id, time3
FROM MyOtherTable

INSERT INTO MyTable
(id, times)
SELECT id, time4
FROM MyOtherTable
```

Or, you could do the following which would keep duplicates from being inserted ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05502/1/0)):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(id, times)
SELECT id, time1
FROM MyOtherTable
UNION 
SELECT id, time2
FROM MyOtherTable
UNION
SELECT id, time3
FROM MyOtherTable
UNION
SELECT id, time4
FROM MyOtherTable
```

Comment: Thanks @Linger. your second solution is working fine for now. the only problem i'm having is, it's populating the new table's times column in ascending order. I'm guessing the data format of the column is doing that. because none of the time columns are actually time data format. is there any trick with the data format here?

Comment: It really shouldn't matter how it inserts the records.  When you query the table for the information you can specify the order by then.  However, if your data type is varchar for instance it won't sort right for you.  That is, not in order based on the time.  Instead it would sort by numeric alpha order, as shown in this [**example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb5ae1/1/0).

Comment: Right the data formats are in varchar and that's why its sorting in numerical order. I actually need to sort using the time.

Comment: You could use the `CONVERT()` function in the `ORDER BY` like the following [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb5ae1/3/0).

Answer (score 1):

That the definition of `UNPIVOT`. If you're using SQLServer 2005 or better you can use

```
INSERT INTO OtherTable
SELECT id, [time]
FROM   (SELECT id, time1, time2, time3, time4 FROM Table1) t
       UNPIVOT
       ([time] FOR times IN (time1, time2, time3, time4)) pvt
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b3379/1)

`UNPIVOT` require that all the columns that are unpivoted have the same type and dimension

Comment: I think i'm going with Linger's solution for now. I never used UNPIVOT so i'll try this later if that doesn't work well. thanks @Serpiton